# Ubuntu fails to "Suspend"

Tags: 14.04, suspend

If I try to "Suspend", the screen turns black for a second or two, and then again wakes up, with screen locked!

This is the output of `cat /var/log/syslog | grep PM:`

```
Feb 11 02:44:09 jatinderjit-Ub kernel: [26195.134484] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Feb 11 02:44:09 jatinderjit-Ub kernel: [26195.395730] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Feb 11 02:44:13 jatinderjit-Ub kernel: [26196.420775] PM: Entering mem sleep
Feb 11 02:44:13 jatinderjit-Ub kernel: [26198.459570] PM: Device 0000:01:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -16
Feb 11 02:44:13 jatinderjit-Ub kernel: [26198.459631] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
Feb 11 02:44:13 jatinderjit-Ub kernel: [26199.673575] PM: resume of devices complete after 1212.554 msecs
Feb 11 02:44:13 jatinderjit-Ub kernel: [26199.673994] PM: Finishing wakeup.
```

---

Output of `cat /var/log/pm-suspend.log`:

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Thu Feb 11 02:44:08 IST 2016: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux jatinderjit-Ub 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
usb_storage            62209  0 
ctr                    13049  0 
ccm                    17773  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  8 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
arc4                   12608  2 
ath9k                 164164  0 
intel_rapl             18773  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
mac80211              630669  1 ath9k
coretemp               13435  0 
i915                  784111  4 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
nouveau              1097199  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
snd_hda_intel          56531  3 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
kvm_intel             143187  0 
kvm                   455835  1 kvm_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
cfg80211              484040  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
ttm                    85150  1 nouveau
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
ath3k                  13318  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
btusb                  32412  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
drm_kms_helper         55071  2 i915,nouveau
bluetooth             391136  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
drm                   303102  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
aesni_intel            55624  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 18627  0 
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
snd                    69322  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
wmi                    19177  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
joydev                 17381  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
shpchp                 37032  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  2 i915,nouveau
soundcore              12680  1 snd
lpc_ich                21080  0 
video                  19476  2 i915,nouveau
mac_hid                13205  0 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
ahci                   29915  3 
psmouse               106714  0 
r8169                  67581  0 
libahci                32716  1 ahci
mii                    13934  1 r8169
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3824248    3000160     824088     361408     168664     676900
-/+ buffers/cache:    2154596    1669652
Swap:      3969020     461612    3507408
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01laptop-mode suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01laptop-mode suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
stop: Unknown instance: 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Thu Feb 11 02:44:08 IST 2016: performing suspend
sh: echo: I/O error
Thu Feb 11 02:44:13 IST 2016: Awake.
Thu Feb 11 02:44:13 IST 2016: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01laptop-mode resume suspend:
Laptop mode 
enabled, active
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01laptop-mode resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
Failed.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

Thu Feb 11 02:44:13 IST 2016: Finished.
```

---

PS: The issue was resolved after a restart, but what could be the possible causes? There wasn't any USB device connected.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `cat /var/log/pm-suspend.log`?
<br>
You could also try removing all USB devices from the computer before suspending.

Answer (score 2):

In your BIOS setup there can be a setting to `Wake on LAN` or `Wake on USB`. If these are on turn them off and see if that fixes the problem.

I've also found that a bad USB cable connected to a powered-hub can generate error messages in dmesg but I'm not sure if that would wake up the system.

### Update February 8, 2020

These lines in your log file:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.
```

Are perhaps the reason `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant` was created as described in this [discussion](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=835648). Check if this file exists and if not see this:

- [Not able to suspend because of Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil) error: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972433/not-able-to-suspend-because-of-failed-to-connect-to-non-global-ctrl-ifname-nil)